# Changing color of panel in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I changed the color of 2 panels on my software with code because I couldnt find the colors I wanted in the properties. And it design windows doesnt refresh, Should it be like that or did I mess up?

This is the code I used

```
private void leftsidePanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    leftsidePanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#333E47");
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    stockPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D67D39");
}
```

[Here is how it looks, The one a bit below and to the right is the debugged one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXk6C.png)

Comment: You can convert to int and put the int into the property field. Or enter RGB values: `18; 214; 202` Or enter as hex: `0x33;0x3e;0x47`. This will be converted to byte but still work fine in the designer..

Comment: @Thomas Oh wow.. eh I have never done that before so do you think you could dummy it down a little bit?

Comment: Well, the last version of my comment is pretty simple to follow: You know those hex values, so you enter them as I have shown.. Note that you can enter text into the color property field! `0x` is the c# prefix for hex numbers.

Comment: Oh I feel silly, I tried adding it to the font instead of the color! Thank you sir!

Comment: @Thomas Thats weird.. It changes it in the ForeColor but it doesnt change it iin the Design window
https://i.gyazo.com/81c8c1553388377b22f9f6f7d74dda05.png

Comment: @Vinnym.George recompile or restart vs, sometimes its buggy

Comment: I tried both, still no success

Comment: ForeColor? BackColor? Also: Sometimes you have to __unselect__ the control to see the changes in the designer or else it tries to make things look readable instead of simply show the colors we wanted! Good night ;-)

Comment: Yup I just saw it, oh my god, I need sleep thank you so much guys!